# How do I fix CSS dropdown list animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have a problem with my `dropdown` list animation. For some reason it animates only text in a `ul` list instead of whole list item blocks.

[How it should work](https://codepen.io/alphanel/pen/KZmorq)

[Incorrect code](https://codepen.io/alphanel/pen/NXgOoo)

```
li:hover > ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(1) {
    animation-name: menu1;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover > ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name: menu1;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-delay: 50ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover > ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(3) {
    animation-name: menu1;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-delay: 100ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menu1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotateY(10deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you added an **opaque** background to the `ul` and a **transparent** one to the element inside it so the animation works well but you don't see it.

You should do the opposite, so you have to remove background and box shadow from `ul`:

```
.dropdown-content {
    ..
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow:visible; /* to see the box-shadow of its childs */
    ...
}
```

Then make them on the inner elements:

```
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Full code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  overflow:visible;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
}

li a:hover.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0ed64d;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 273px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav_bar {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

li:hover>ul.dropdown-content {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

li:hover>ul.dropdown-content a {
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover>ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-name: menu1;
  animation-name: menu1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
  animation-delay: 0ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover>ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-name: menu1;
  animation-name: menu1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 50ms;
  animation-delay: 50ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover>ul.dropdown-content a:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-name: menu1;
  animation-name: menu1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes menu1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(10deg);
    transform: rotateY(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes menu1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(10deg);
    transform: rotateY(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='nav_bar'>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <a>Link 1</a>
      <a>Link 2</a>
      <a>Link 3</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="#news">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='div' style="z-index:1;padding:20px;;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">


  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to apply a background and a box-shadow on .dropdown-content

```
.dropdown-content
  display: none
  position: absolute
  background-color: transparent
  min-width: 100px  
  box-shadow: unset
```